# Line up elements using CSS

Tags: jquery, css

Having an issue lining up elements using CSS.

I am appending a text box to a cloned object and for some reason I cant seem to get margin to work on the text box using CSS. I cant figure out the issue. Here's the code:

JS:

```
$('.newImg').append($(this).clone()) 

    var textarea = '<textarea cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>';
    $('.newImg').append(textarea);
```

Part of CSS

```
.newImg img {
  border: 5px solid lightgreen;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 250px;
}
 textarea {
  margin-top: 220px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

Part of HTML:

```
<div class ="newImg"> </div>
```

Comment: `textarea` has `display:inline` by default, so `margin-top`/`-bottom` do not have any effect. Try adding `display:inline-block`

Comment: `$('.newImg').append(textarea);` would append a textarea to every element with the newImg class, not just the most recently appended one. And that brings me to `$('.newImg').append($(this).clone())` which isn't correct, unless `this` has context from other code you have.

Comment: @CBroe - What browser would that be? Chrome and IE11 force textareas computed display value to be inline-block. Firefox computes it to inline, but gives effect to top and bottom margins on textareas anyway, treating them in that respect as if they were either inline replaced elements, or inline-block.

Comment: display:inline-block didn't seem to do the trick. 

this - has context from other code

Comment: Any other thoughts on how to fix it? I'm stuck